# Cassandra doesn't wait for nodes to be available

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm using the datastax driver for java:

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Insert
    CompletableFuture<Void> save(MyEntity entity);
    ...
}

public class MyDaoTests {
    
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
    ...
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futureList = myEntityList.parallelStream()
             .map((myEntity) -> meterDataMapper.myDao().save(myEntity))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futureList.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
    ...
   }
}
```

When I execute the test, I get this error:
`java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query`

Is there a way to configure the driver/session to wait for available nodes?

Further information:

- My test size is about 2500000 entities (`myEntityList`).
- Synchronous inserts work fine, but they're way too slow.
- I want to solve this with the [datastax-java-driver mapper](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/4.x/manual/mapper), annotation-based, as simple as possible.
- Driver Version: 4.9.0

Comment: looks like you have a spring boot project, can you share it on github ? and I had no node available exception before and solved by configuring throttling https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/throttling/ do you use it ?

Answer (score 0):

The `NoNodeAvailableException` is returned when the driver has marked all nodes as down or unresponsive, or when the contact points are invalid (not likely in your case).

It isn't a case of making the driver wait for nodes to come back online. Since the driver thinks all the nodes are unavailable, it doesn't even try to connect to any nodes.

Review the logs on the nodes for clues as to why they're unresponsive. If you're seeing long GC pauses and/or dropped reads/mutations, they are a sign that the nodes are overloaded. If you're running a load test, consider throttling the throughput back so as not to overload your cluster. Cheers!

Comment: When I limit the concurrent queries to 255, it works without exceptions. If I go up to 256, those exceptions appear again. I need to know where this number is coming from and I'm wondering why the client doesn't throttle by itself.

Comment: I made a [github project](https://github.com/nodueck/cassandratest) which shows the issue. If you set the max-concurrent-requests = 1024 everything is fine. If you set it back to 1025 NoNodeAvailableExceptions appear. (I've testet this 5 times with each value). Also I don't see any issue in the logs. The gc.log.0 shows a "total time for which app threads were stopped" of max 0.1 seconds.